# Azure DevOps on-premise cannot verify Kubernetess service connection

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2020, serviceconnection

I am creating **New Kubernetes service connection**  in **Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1** via KubeConfig.

When I click to **Verify** that the connection it says that **Verification Failed** with the generic error:

*Failed to query service connection API: 'https://ekm.mpu.cz/k8s/clusters/c-qmcrb/api/v1/nodes'. Error Message: 'An error occurred while sending the request.'*

[image]

Please note that the Kubernetess instance is in the other domain.

I have the notion that the error could be with the certs are not imported somewhere on the machine, where the Azure DevOps is hosted, but I am unsure where. The MS documentation is silent about that as well.

So far I've tried to:

- Import CA certs to the MMC under trusted publishers.
- Import CA certs under cacerts in JAVA-HOME via keytool.
- Import CA certs into azureTrustsStore.jks in JAVA-HOME via keytool.

For all 3 I've checked that the CA certs are imported correctly. But to no avail. Could you please advice or redirect me to the method, how to do it?

Additional Info:

While I cannot Verify and Save the connection, I still can Save it and then use it in the pipeline and it works OK! (sucesfully connect and execute the command).

Answer (score 0):

Connection issues can occur for many reasons, but the root cause is often related to an error with one of these items: Network, Authentication, Authorization. You may refer to [Basic troubleshooting of cluster connection issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/troubleshoot-cluster-connection-issues-api-server) for detailed troubleshooting steps.